# Why would an IIS hosted site prompt for AD account credential if accessed through a hostname or IP, but not through servername?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, windows-nano-server

I have a webservice running in IIS hosted in a Windows 2016 Nano server. I can access the service just fine if I go through `http://servername/service/health`

However, if i were to access it via `http://[IP Address here]/service/health` or `http://service.company.com/service/health`, it would prompt for AD login credential.

I looked through the DNS record and the IIS ApplicationHost.config and I can't really tell what's wrong with it. I might have missed a setting or two. Can anyone figure out where to look or what to do?

Comment: For IE, the cause is the periods in that URL, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password Other browsers might follow IE's behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a Kerberos issue; if I'm correct, then the server's AD computer account(*) has a registered SPN for `HTTP/SERVERNAME` (this can be verified with the `SETSPN` command-line tool), thus automatic Kerberos authentication can happen when the web service is called using the computer's name; however, when calling the web service with any other name, this won't work.

If you want to be able to call the web service using a different name, then you need to add another SPN to the same AD computer account(*), with a command such as `SETSPN -S HTTP/service.company.com SERVERNAME`.

More info [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/717.service-principal-names-spn-setspn-syntax.aspx).

(*) Or the user account which runs IIS's application pool, if you manually configured one.

Comment: When i do "setspn -L servername" I do see the servername in the list and I added HTTP/service.company.com, but it still won't work. Another thing I noticed is that servername.companyname.com is listed under the same service classes as servername, but using that will give me a prompt for credential.

Comment: The other thing is, the actual web application should be configured to accept that hostname; f.e. SharePoint needs a manual configuration for this. But I don't know your application, so I can't voice for that.

Comment: Quick mention of some SETSPN options which *probably aren't* the issue here, but might be useful in general when troubleshooting this. Use -Q (and -X) to search for any possible duplicate SPNs associated with the wrong account. But generally, if you're testing in IE, the client needs to consider the target site part of the Local Intranet Zone in order to automatically authenticate. (see parts of this answer https://serverfault.com/a/352180/35088 as well)

Answer (score 4):

Service.company.com would need to be a registered Service Principal Name on the IIS server.

Also, Kerberos integrated authentication by default will not work with an IP address unless the system is configured to do so, and the IP address is a registered Service Principal Name.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/configuring-kerberos-over-ip

Answer (score 2):

One other check - it is possible your browser isn't passing credentials, forcing the login prompt.

In Internet Options, there is a security zone for Local Intranet; this zone will automatically pass your Windows credentials without the need for the AD dialog.  The default setting will detect the server name as part of your network, but the full domain name is probably considered Internet zone and doesn't send the credentials.  In the configuration page for Local Intranet, you can add the FQDN to no longer be prompted (or set it via Group Policy).

This all assumes you intend the site to run with Windows Credentials, and you are running internally; I'm not a security expert but personally, I wouldn't want to send my credentials automatically to a site across the internet.